# After Merge Js Admin panel menu not work?

Tags: magento-1.9, js-css, merge-css

I have merge `recently css and js from magento backend`. after this **backend menu** not work i got following error.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

I dont know what is problem with this.

Comment: You have to check manually which JS causes conflict..First disable custom  modules and enable one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you have load prototype.js before jquery-your-version.js .
you will find this in your main.xml

```
<block type="adminhtml/page" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page.phtml">
           <block type="adminhtml/page_head" name="head" as="head" template="page/head.phtml">
                <action method="setTitle" translate="title"><title>Magento Admin</title></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>js/jquery.js</name><params/><if/><condition>can_load_ext_js</condition></action>
```